# How to take two specific words from an Excel sheet and add them to another column with Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-analysis, data-cleaning

I need to clean my data.

I want to add a new column with only the words "IN" or "OUT".

[image: picture of full data where the words "IN" and "OUT" are]

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_excel("tourniquets_26.07.2022_test.xls") #Read Excel as file as Dataframe

#My try to use a loop to find it
for word in df["Deur intelligente eenheid"]:
    if word == "IN" or word == "UIT":
        df['IN/UIT'] = word
#Display top 5 rows  
print(df.head(5))

#To save it back as Excel
df.to_excel("tourniquets_26.07.2022_test.xls") #Write DataFrame back as Excel file
```

Comment: So, in excel, if(iferror(find(" IN ",A1,1)>1,0),"IN","") which you can duplicate for "OUT" or "UIT"...

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, the logic would be that the column in your current df always has (somewhere within it) either the word "IN" our "UIT", and you want a new column that has *only* the corresponding "IN" or "UIT" word, right?

If so, you can use `Series.apply` to do this. Create a function that returns "IN" or "UIT" depending on what word is in a sentence:

```
def my_fun(sentence):
    if "IN" in sentence:
        return "IN"
   else: #assuming that if it doesn't contain "IN", it must contain "UIT"
        return "UIT"
```

and apply this to df["col_1"] to create a new column. Assuming your column is called "col_1":

```
df['IN/UIT'] = df["col_1"].apply(my_fun)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.where:

```
import numpy as np
df['IN/UIT'] = np.where(df['col'].str.startswith('IN'), 'IN', 'UIT')
```